# Django if tag doesn't work here

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a blog app and i want to show each post in a very different way using classes and showing/not-showing parts, based in a foreign key value "postype".
This is my code:

```
{% for post in posts.object_list %}
    <div class="{{ post.postype }}">
        <h4>{{ post.title }}</h4>
        {% if post.postype == 'Post' %}<p>{{ post.created }}</p>{% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

And the result of that is:

```
<div class="Post">
    Title Post One
</div>
<div class="News">
    Title Post Two
</div>
<div class="Post">
    Title Post Three
</div>
```

So my question is, why the "post.created" is not showing even though the div class shows "Post" in two cases?, which means the if should match.

This is the model i'm using

```
class Postype(models.Model):
    postype = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.postype

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    postype = models.ForeignKey(Postype)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    text = models.TextField()
    allow_comments = models.BooleanField(db_index=True, default=True)
    published = models.BooleanField(db_index=True, default=True)

    objects = PostManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
    return u"%s - %s" % (self.title, self.created) 

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slughifi(self.title)
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show what model is being used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If post.posttype is a foreign key to another model, you need to specify what attribute of posttype you want to compare against

so if

```
class PostType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
```

you should have

```
{% if post.posttype.name == "Post" %}...{% endif %}
```

As it stands you are comparing an object (posttype) to a string ("Post") which will always fail.

The reason the div shows the class "Post" correctly, is because django is automatically guessing how to display the Post model when you don't specify a field. To change the way a post is printed when no attribute is given, you can overwrite the **unicode** method of the model:

```
class PostType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

This means that when you reference this post type (like in your question as ) the **unicode** method is called which returns self.name

Comment: Missed the fact that it said ForeignKey at the top.  I would use the direct path (post.postype.name) rather than a `def __unicode__(self):` incase something changes in the future.

Comment: post.postype.postype did it, that,s how i have in the model and it worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: I re-read your answer, this is really the type of answer that really help me understand, i'm a designer, not a programmer. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried double quotes instead of single quotes in the `if` statement?

Comment: Yes, i did try that before, but it was actually what @pastylegs said. Thank you :)